# Could not resolve org.scaldingspoon.gradle:gradle-waroverlay-plugin:0.9.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, cas, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Suddunly got an error which state that

```
     Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':common:security:cas-server:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.scaldingspoon.gradle:gradle-waroverlay-plugin:0.9.3.
     Required by:
         project :common:security:cas-server
      > Could not resolve org.scaldingspoon.gradle:gradle-waroverlay-plugin:0.9.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/scaldingspoon/gradle/gradle-waroverlay-plugin/0.9.3/gradle-waroverlay-plugin-0.9.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/scaldingspoon/gradle/gradle-waroverlay-plugin/0.9.3/gradle-waroverlay-plugin-0.9.3.pom'. Received status code 401 from server:
```

tried by changing version and all, but still got the issue

```
**Gradle Version: 6.8.3**

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.scaldingspoon.gradle:gradle-waroverlay-plugin:0.9.3"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'waroverlay'

war {
    includeWarJars = true
    entryCompression = ZipEntryCompression.STORED
```

}

Comment: How did you import plugin?

Comment: It seems pretty clean from the 401, try getting ```https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/scaldingspoon/gradle/gradle-waroverlay-plugin/0.9.3/gradle-waroverlay-plugin-0.9.3.pom``` by just pasting it in the browser using your credentials.

Comment: resolved the issue by changing the dependencies. posted the changes as answer. Thank you for the replay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by  changing dependencies.

```
dependencies {
            classpath "io.freefair.war-overlay:io.freefair.war-overlay.gradle.plugin:0.10.0"
             }
apply plugin: "io.freefair.war-overlay"

war {
    //includeWarJars = true - this line removed
    entryCompression = ZipEntryCompression.STORED
}
```